# copy from one folder to another not working in terminal

Tags: command-line

I'm new to Ubuntu. I installed it because i'm using it in my operating systems class in college.  One thing needed to do is copy.  This is the lecturers notes on how to do this:
Change to your home directory

```
cd
```

Display a listing of the files contained within it in long format

```
ls -al
```

Make a directory here called test

```
mkdir test
```

Below test create two directories x and y

```
cd test
mkdir x
mkdir y
```

Copy the file fstab from the /etc directory to the directory y

```
cd y
cp /etc/fstab .
```

But it's not working. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: you might want to check the permissions of the /etc directory using ls -ld /etc for umask of 002 it must be rwx-r_x-r_x(755).

Comment: @OliveTwist Just the copy step everything else is fine.

Comment: @Ankit  Thanks man.  yeah its read/write

Comment: @Ankit I suggest you to add an answer with a bit more details. It will help future visitors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to copy a file you must have read permission on the parent directory of the file and write permission on the destination.

Think of directory as a container with a lock and file as contents of the container.

You must have an access to the keys of the lock in order to access the file inside the directory(container).

```
File Permissions:-
```

r - can read the file.

w - can write to a file.

x - can run the file as a program.

```
Directory Permissions:-
```

r - can read the contents of the directory.

w - can make changes to files inside the directory/ add or delete the files.

x - can `cd` to a directory.

Directory permissions are important and can override the file permissions.

Even if you're file doesn't have read permissions but the parent directory of the file has a read permission than you can copy the file assuming that you're copying the file to a location where you can write.

I assume this might be helpful.